# Is there any way in Python to check if a string contains a real-world location?

Tags: python, location

Most likely if there is any library that analyzes the String and then returns any possible location that is in there?

For example:
"foo foobar foot New York foo" would, obviously, return "New York".

Comment: Analyzing the string can be done using different techniques. Starting with regular expressions to information extraction using natural language processing. What direction are you heading towards ?

Comment: The problem is very ill-defined, but do you expect this library to detect https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman%2C_Iran and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accident,_Maryland from the string "Batman arrived too late at the location of the accident" ?

Comment: @birsingh Wouldn't that need to have certain premade locations then? I mean that is an hipothesis but if there was already a list of locations or something that I could use would be a lot easier.

Comment: @FBergo It's mostly for a real time disaster warning using a GIS and with the filtered tweets, from the text, I was trying to gather locations, if some of those end up being wrong or innaccurate that would be fine, for now.

Comment: you could use a pre-built dictionary of locations ( i would search google for that) for a lookup solution, but you would still need to extract location information from the string.

Comment: @birsingh Well guess I better brush up on my regex then. I found a library called geograpy tho, struggling to install it since it appears to be an old one but if I do manage I'll edit my post.

Comment: @BryceSoker the hardest task here is to gather a meaningful list of locations. Having every possible town/province in the world will get you way too many false positives, and you would need semantic analysis of the text (not just simple grep'ing) to evaluate each case. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a list with locations you want to search for, then iterate over that list comparing the location with the string using `in`.

```
mystring = 'hello new york foo'
locations = ['new york', 'dallas']
for location in locations:
    if location in mystring:
        print(location)
>new york
```

You would have to find out what locations you are looking for beforehand however. You might also want to format mystring to lowercase.

Comment: Yep, I guess the only way to do it properly is if we have already a list of locations, thanks, i'll go ahead and place this as the correct answer.